# How to get the file name extension without actually knowing the extension

Tags: php

I have been trying this PHP code to get the **extension** of a file without actually knowing it. But I get this error **Undefined offset: 0**

My file name looks like this: **adImage-9-3-1**

Is it still possible to get the extension when file name contains one or more *hyphens*?

This is my PHP code:

```
    $fileName = "adImage-" . $ImageId . "-" . $adId . "-" . $userId . "*"; //used * to check for other possible results

    $fileInfo = glob($fileName);

    $fileExt = explode(".", $fileInfo[0]); //throws Undefined Offset:0 error
    $fileActualExt = $fileExt[1];

    print_r($fileActualExt); //empty output
```

I get this error as mentioned above:

> **Undefined offset: 0**

Comment: Glob will returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error. are you sur $fileInfo is not an empty array? Perhaps your missing a directory path to your images unless they are located at the same place your fil is?

Comment: show the $fileInfo . what data inside ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If the file is named `adImage-9-3-1`, which "extension" should be returned? As fas as I see, that file name has none

Answer (score 3):

You can use this on your unknown file to see its extension:

```
pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
```

To see the result:

```
var_dump(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Comment: What do you mean by `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` ?

Comment: It shows the extension of a file. the $file variable is your file path. Try it and see the results.